# weirdness with java timestamp -- simple test fails?

Tags: java, timestamp

here's my test:

```
long stamp = 1471314737L;//unix timestamp for 16 Aug 2016...
Timestamp test = new Timestamp(stamp);
System.out.println("test = " + test.toString());
```

1970-01-17 16:41:54.737

what's up with that?

Comment: Try multiplying your timestamp x1000 as your timestamp is in seconds and new Timestamp(timestamp) constructor takes number of milliseconds

Answer (score 2):

> Timestamp(long time) Constructs a Timestamp object using a
>   milliseconds time value.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html

Try multiplying your timestamp by 1000?